# Reshaping a Factor in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following character string:

```
str(seqN)  
chr [1:704] "010000100100001010000100010001000100000100101000010001001000001001001000001000010010000100100100010000101000010"| __truncated__ ...
```

Yes they are very long strings (704 strings of length 1000) composed of 0s and 1s. They are meant to be a sequence already one-hot encoded.

Since I want to feed that to a Convolutional model, I need a certain input shape, so I want to split each string into subgroups of length 4 (to match the one-hot encoding).

The problem is that R doesn't let me split that string, as if the string was unsplittable.

For example, If I execute this code:

```r
seqN2 <- array_reshape(seqN,c(704,250,4))
```

It gives me this error:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
>     ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 704 into shape (704,250,4)

What should I do to achieve that shape I need (704,250,4)?

Comment: Try with `strsplit(seqN, "(?<=.{4})", perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Seems to do the trick, but I don't know if its structure is what I need. I'm going to see if I can feed it to the model.

Comment: What shape do you want your output to be in?

Comment: @Cett (704, 250,4). I've editted the original post with it so it is clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` from `base R`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(seqN, "(?<=.{4})", perl = TRUE)
```

The output will be a `list` of `vector`s.  Not sure about the conversion to numeric.  May be

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, strtoi, base = 2)
```

Or as OP mentioned in the comments, it is convert just to integer

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, as.integer)
```

If they are of the same length, it could be also converted to a `matrix` by `rbind`ing the `list` elements

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lst2)
```

Comment: That does the trick yes, unfortunately it works as a list of substrings and I'm struggling to convert those substrings to integers to feed the model.

Comment: @JaimeMartínez  It would be a `list` of vectors.  if you can show what your intended output would be, it may be useful.  `do.call(rbind, strsplit(seqN,  "(?<=.{4})", perl = TRUE))` converts to a matrix

Comment: that works better, yes. With your tip, after reshaping, I've got a matrix of dimensions (704, 250). The desired outpout should be (704, 250, 4), I'll try splitting in substrings of only one character (instead of 4) and then reshaping the matrix.

Comment: I've seen your edit @akrun. I did the conversion to numeric simply with as.integer. Then I did a reshape of that array.

Comment: @JaimeMartínez  I was thinking that the `"0100"` or `"0010"` when converted with `as.integer`, it will become only 1.  So, I used `strtroi`

Comment: Oh I see. In the end it just removed the zeroes to the left, so "0100" turned to 100.

Comment: Ok, in that case, it is just `as.integer`

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple way you can split a long string into substrings of length 4.
Just adjust the variable `n` according to your needs:

```
mystring <- "110010101101"
n <- 2 # n <- nchar(mystring) / 4 -1

sapply(1 + 4*0:n, function(z) substr(mychar, z, z+3))
[1] "1100" "1010" "1101"
```

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for, since it lets me convert the characters to integers without messing anything up. Don't know if that's exactly what my model wants but I'll find out now.

Comment: Ok so this definetly worked, although akrun's solution gets the same result in just one line.

Answer (score 2):

You could you `stringr` to extract all sequences up to 4 characters:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(seqN, ".{1,4}", simplify = T)[1,]
 [1] "0100" "0010" "0100" "0010" "1000" "0100" "0100" "0100" "0100" "0001" "0010" "1000" "0100" "0100" "1000" "0010" "0100" "1000" "0010"
[20] "0001" "0010" "0001" "0010" "0100" "0100" "0010" "1000" "010"
```